# Can't see my downloaded app on iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-transfer

I bought the Spark Radio app through iTunes and apparently it was downloaded, but I don't see the app on the iPad.  How can I get the app I purchased to appear on teh iPad?

Comment: Just in case it's simply of matter of your not *seeing* it despite it being there somewhere, slide your pages of apps in Springboard to the right until Spotlight search appears and type `spark` -- if the app appears then it's somewhere on your iPad already.

Comment: Do you have enough space left on the iPad? You actually need a little more than the app size, because the app also needs additional space during installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see the app in iTunes but not on your iPad, it means that it didn't sync over. Make sure it is selected as an app to sync.  Alternatively, try downloading it using the app store app on your ipad.

Comment: And, you can turn on Automatic Downloads in iTunes Preferences, so that purchased items on one device are downloaded to all.